# Nested annotations method interception in Guice

Tags: java, guice, interceptor

I searched a lot but couldn't find anything much useful.

**Problem:**
I have created custom annotation like:

```
@MapExceptions(value = {
        @MapException(sources = {IllegalArgumentException.class, RuntimeException.class}, destination = BadRequestException.class),
        @MapException(sources = {RuntimeException.class}, destination = BadRequestException.class)
})
```

I am using Guice for DI.

1. Do I have to write two method interceptors? Actual work is getting done in @MapException
2. If yes, then how can I call @MapException interceptors invoke method from @MapExceptions interceptors invoke method? I dont want to duplicate code.
3. My @MapException interceptor looks like following

public class MapExceptionInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

```
@Override
public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
    try {
        return invocation.proceed();
    } catch (Exception actualException) {
        Method method = invocation.getMethod();
        Annotation[] annotations = method.getDeclaredAnnotations();
        for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
            if (annotation instanceof MapException) {
                MapException mapException = (MapException) annotation;
                Class<? extends Throwable> destinationClass = mapException.destination();
                Class<? extends Throwable>[] sourceClasses = mapException.sources();
                for (Class sourceExceptionClass : sourceClasses) {
                    if (actualException.getClass().isInstance(sourceExceptionClass)) {
                        Constructor ctr = destinationClass.getConstructor(String.class);
                        throw (Throwable) ctr.newInstance(actualException.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        throw actualException;
    }
}
```

}

I am using following Binding currently

```
bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.annotatedWith(MapException.class), new MapExceptionInterceptor());
```

Is this okay? Or I can improve?

Thank You !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the inner annotation is just a data bag. 
To solve this I wrote interceptor for outer annotation (MapExceptions) which does all the work.

Comment: Can you provide the code that you used to solve this?